# Event does not hook up correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

Not sure if i will be able to formulate my question quite clear but let me try:

So i've written a small piece of code which will give the user the option to select a desired status for his Office Communicator when his PC get locked ( by default it goes automatically on status "away" ) .So here it is the Windows Form wich is basically a combobox and a button .The Combo has four option "Away" , "Busy" , Do not Disturb" and "Online" respectively. All seems fine and the program compiles ok.The Menu appears , you select the status you wish , push the button and then lock your PC - so far all goes perfect.Your Status is as selected .And now comes the Problem.You unlock your PC and try to select a different status , same actions , but when you lock the PC it still shows the previously selected status here is the Button_Click method

```
public void Btn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // When the button is clicked,
    // change the button text, and disable it.     
    if (Comb.Text == "Away")
    {    
        MessageBox.Show("Saved ! \nYour Status will be 'Away' ");
        Method2();
    }

    else if (Comb.Text == "Busy")
    {       
        MessageBox.Show("Saved ! \nYour Status will be  'Busy' ");
        Method1();    
    }

    else if (Comb.Text == "Do Not Disturb")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Saved ! \nYour Status will be 'Do Not Disturb' ");
        Method3();
    }

    else
    {   
        MessageBox.Show("Saved ! \nYour Status will be 'Online' ");
        Method4();
    }

    But.Enabled = true;
    // Display the greeting label text.
}
```

So the 4 methods ( Method1 () , 2 ... etc ) are the one to change the status depending on the text in the combo box drop down menu ( the status you select )i have tested all methods separately from each other and they work beautiful thereforfe i exclude a problems with them , is it some logical error ?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're going to be using an edition of visual express or visual studio. Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the Click_Event and debug the program?

Comment: Is it the same scenario with different first selections? it's not the code you've posted that fails. It basically does nothing on it's own. So if you debug and find the code that actually breaks post that and I'm sure you'll get an answer before you can spell 'debug' backwards :)

Comment: Rune FS , it doesnt matter what will be your first selection , its always the same scenario

Comment: please check if there's some other piece of code changing your ComboBox. usually the solution to these problems is outside

Comment: Can we see the code for one of the numbered Methods? It might help see why you're not overriding an already existent value.

Comment: Yes Jeremy below the Method1 () ( its identical with the other methods )

Comment: public static void Method1 ()
   
   
  {
  
  SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch1);
  
    
  }

Comment: also here is the SystemEvents_SessionSwitch1 method

Answer (score 0):

```
static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch1(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        CommunicatorAPI.MessengerClass comm = new CommunicatorAPI.MessengerClass();

        if (comm.MyStatus==MISTATUS.MISTATUS_AWAY)
        {
            SetMyPresence1 ();
        } else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock)
        {
            ChangeStatus1 ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens within SetMyPresence1()? This is presumably where the status is supposed to change...

Comment: Hi Mark , SetMyPresence is basically where the status is changed its quite straightforward and i have tested it many times before that so i don't expect the issue to come from this line

Answer (score 0):

Nikolay, give [SharpDevelop's debugger](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/pages/FeatureTourDebugging.aspx) a try.  In your code's margin click once next to the line `if (Comb.Text == "Away")` and then hover over the variable names to see what they are set to each time it runs.  You can use the "Step over" "Step into" and "Step out" functions to "Execute the highlighted method without looking at the internals", "Debug the Internals of a method" or "Run the current method to the end and then show the next level up" respectively.

If you do this you'll figure out *why* you're getting an error and it will be MUCH easier to determine where the error is coming from. (For instance, if a variable is set to an unexpected value you'll know to figure out when that changed).